# After deploying app to Heroku, the API_URL config variable get prepended by the URL of my current app causing wrong request URLs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I'm running two separate apps (Create-react-app frontend & a node/express backend) on Heroku. I'm trying to make a request from the info-screen.herokuapp.com to the info-screen-backend one.

This is the GET request handler:

```
app.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    Info.find()
    .then( info => {
        res.status(200).json(info)
    })
    .catch( err => {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: err
        });
    });
});
```

And here you can see the frontend side that actually sends the requests:

```
 axios.get(API_URI + '/info')
    .then( (resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Here is the config var for the API_URI env variable:

[image: Config var]

I've been searching for a fix for this for about two hours now.

Whenever I send a request, for some reason the frontend tries to prefix the API_URI variable with it's own URI resulting in this (Look at the Request URL):

[image: Request]

Has anyone here maybe had any experience with this? I tried to google around and thought maybe create-react-app was using BaseUrl or something but apparently it's not.

When I send a request to the API directly it returns this normally:

```
[
  {
    "created_by": "Innkaupadeild",
    "show": false,
    "_id": "5e67b5b4070f000004a62c79",
    "title": "New shipment on hold",
    "details": "New shipment on testing 2",
    "created_date": "2020-03-10T15:43:48.710Z",
    "modified_date": "2020-03-10T15:43:48.710Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Meaning that this is definitely on the frontend site.

Am I missing maybe something in my package.json or is there another file that I need in order to allow heroku to make external requests?

The buildpack that I'm using on the frontend is ["Mars Create-React-Buildpack"](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

Comment: Should the API_URI not be `https://info-screen.herokuapp.com` maybe it's just because the image cuts of part of the value but in your typed text you also leave out the protocol part of the url.

Comment: You are a G E N I U S! I can't believe I wasted so much time on this just for it to be THIS. Please put an answer to the question so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Hey man, @Ikzturb, could you please help figure out how you solved this problem? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hey @AaronVasilev, sorry for the late reply lmao. Hopefully you have figured it out already. 

The issue was caused by me leaving out the http protocol out of the url. Axios thought it was a relative url instead of an absolute one, thus appending it to the base url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the API_URI not be `https://info-screen.herokuapp.com` maybe it's just because the image cuts of part of the value but in your typed text you also leave out the protocol part of the url